# PHP/Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory when using docker-compose and MySql none standard port

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I have the following docker-compose file to build a LAMP stack:

```
version: "3.1"
services:

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_USER=test
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
    ports:
      - "8052:3306"

  webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./dev/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "8050:80"

  php-fpm:
    build: dev/php-fpm
    container_name: php-fpm
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./dev/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

This gets my stack up and running then in my .env file I have:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=8052
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=test
DB_PASSWORD=test
```

When Laravel tries to connect I get the following error message: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`

After some research I found that changing DB_HOST to 127.0.0.1 changes the way PHP tries to connect (TCP instead of a socket). After trying that I get a different error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

The thing is php artisan migrate works and connects fine. I can also connect to the DB from the CLI and a GUI tool.

Is there something wrong in my docker-compose yaml causing this?

Docker file:

```
FROM php:fpm
WORKDIR "/application"

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractiv

# Install selected extensions and other stuff
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt install ca-certificates apt-transport-https \
    && apt install wget \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql \
    && wget -q https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg -O- | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install php7.3-memcached php7.3-mysql php7.3-redis php7.3-xdebug \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*
```

Nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    client_max_body_size 108M;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;


    root /application/public;
    index index.php;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
        fastcgi_param APP_ENV "dev";
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

Comment: `DB_HOST=mariadb`

Comment: Internal traffic would still use the standard ports (or rather the ports defined in the image / Dockerfile) wouldn't it? Not the host / container mapping?

Comment: @u_mulder that didn't seem to make a difference I still get SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (and configs/cache where cleared)

Comment: @twigg In addition to u_mulder's change, change `DB_PORT=8052` to `DB_PORT=3306`. You _may_ need to add `link` directives, but I'm not sure if those are still valid in v3.

Comment: @JonStirling thank you, that seemed to solve it. Is there anything I can research into to show why 'mariadb' is the host? Is there something internally docker is doing for this to happen?

Comment: Found it. https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ `By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.`

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself unable to run php artisan commands which require database connection after adding "`DB_HOST=mariadb`"

such as:

- php artisan migrate
- php artisan db:seed

**Solution:**

Add the following to your hosts file: 127.0.0.1 [name_of_container]

Name of container in your case is: mariadb

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why should one modify the hosts file manually, if Docker already provides everything? Additionally, **which** file should be edited?